# Change '-' to variable and use this variable to call exact value

Tags: php, variables, key

For example:

```
$k = "+";

$q = 8;
echo $array[$q+1];
```

But I want the following:

```
echo $array[$q$k1];
```

So it basically says "call the value of array which is 8+1 so 9." and  if I want to call 7 I can do $k = "-".

Comment: Could you post some explanation why you want to do this?

Comment: The thing is your variable is a string not an arithmetic operator. I don't understand what the use case for this would be? Maybe better doing similar with a switch?

Comment: I have a system where 2 arrays are being compared to each other. The first array has a string of like 60 charachters with words hidden inside it and the other array has the string of the word. I search for two of the same charachters and if that cahrachter +1 is equel to the next charachter in the big array it goes on untill the whole word is found. But since the words are als from right to left I also have to check left, and changing + to - with a single loop make this way more simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you can not treat operators as variables.

Still, there two basic ways you can achieve the same effect.

You can use a conditional and specify the values accordingly:

```
$r = 1; //the value you're adding; moved to a variable for clarity
$op = '+'; //+ means add; anything else means subtract

echo $array[$q + ($op === '+' ? $r : -$r)];

//or

if($op === '+') {
    echo $array[$q + $r];
} else {
    echo $array[$q - $r];
}
```

Or you can change the operation into a multiplication:

```
echo $array[$q + (($op === '+' ? 1 : -1) * $r)];
```

Either form will work; it's just a matter of what is most convenient for your code.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.